# mobile devices operating systems

Tags: mobile

what are the operating systems which run on mobile devices?On which language are these developed?

Comment: This is not entirely the topic of this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the major smart-phones:

- As of Q2/2009, the majority of smart-phones run [Symbian OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian_OS), and applications are developed using either a specialized version of C++ or a variety of other languages including Python, Java ME, Flash Lite, Ruby, .NET, Web Runtime (WRT) Widgets and Standard C/C++.
- iPhone runs [iPhone OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_OS), and apps are generally developed in [Objective C](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FObjective-C&ei=_RmpS8bdCISBlAeGlOGhDw&usg=AFQjCNGc_j0MKTwKhXSQ_u-UfIW37dENKA&sig2=tt-rSObiJfGkUZ7ojSlzlQ).
- Blackberry runs [BlackBerry OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_OS), and apps are developed using [Java](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJava_(programming_language)&ei=HxqpS-C5IcWclgfZpMmODw&usg=AFQjCNGKH0inB8IwCCr_JtmyqMoTCpTLYA&sig2=nxuRuO8b_I3t6OkfJgWubg).
- Palm Pre runs [webOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebOS), and applications are written in [JavaScript](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJavaScript&ei=MBqpS-HUF4GBlAfY7YmeDw&usg=AFQjCNHLnBxJE9lKOezfWcx-UsS1YY6AQg&sig2=t-exEGdvdgVX6cqChHH_uQ).
- Many newer smart-phone devices run [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29), and apps are developed using Java.
- Many other smart-phones run [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile), and applications would typically be developed using either C++ or languages on the [.NET Compact Framework](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fnetframework%2Faa497273.aspx&ei=tBqpS5MuhoGUB4TatbQP&usg=AFQjCNFWyTSBsD3FUssubYtnojLXioOTQQ&sig2=jda0Wdl4IW6SJIeRHSMDYQ), which include C# and VB.NET.

Comment: @Justin could you please tell what Objective C is?

Comment: Isn't Windows Mobile / .NET missing from your list?  It may not be my favorite, but it should make the list!

Comment: @abson - Objective-C used for client application development on Apple platforms; I just added some links. @Nate - Good catch, just added it.

Comment: Thanks @Justin for taking this trouble
also @Nate for cross checking it

Comment: Applications for Windows Mobile are often developed with C++. .NET is slow even on a desktop, and I very much avoid .NET apps on *my* WM5 palm, as due to their slugishness they all are just a major PITA to use.

Answer (score 1):

For a long list, see [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_operating_system).

Short list of a few currently-popular options:

- RIM devices run BlackBerry OS, apps can be written in Java
- The iPhone/iPad run iPhone OS (OSX derivative), apps can be written in Objective C
- A variety of devices run Windows Mobile, apps can be written in a variety of languages
- A variety of devices run Android, apps are typically written in Java
- Newer Palm devices run WebOS, apps can be written in web languages (HTML 5, CSS, JavaScript)
- A variety of devices run Symbian, apps are typically written in C++ (although other options like Java and Python exist)